# Segmentation fault 11 cURL

Tags: macos, curl, segmentation-fault

## cURL "Segmentation fault: 11"

At some point, I wasn't able to use any php or c (these are the ones i checked) programs that use cURL without the segfault. Nothing has changed besides an xcode update with additional packages. My colleagues do not have this problem though.
I can use cURL manually which works, for example:
`"*- ~$ curl -I https://www.google.com/"`
Initially i thought it was a problem caused by php but it works perfectly fine as long as no cURL is used.

### Things I tried:

- reinstalled cURL
- used Apples' cURL, followed by the one from homebrew, then Apple again
- reinstalled php
- php version from php@7.0.33 homebrew/exolnet to php@7.3.6_1 homebrew
- brew update and upgrade
- brew doctor
- coredump in google (led to several results but not for my problem)

#### System:

- macOS Mojave 10.14.4
- macBook Pro (13", 2016, 16GB Ram)
- php@7.0.33 (exolnet)
- cURL 7.54.0

#### Coredump:

lldb:

```
  thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x000000010a982fe0 libcurl.4.dylib`sh_delentry + 40
    frame #1: 0x000000010a982fa9 libcurl.4.dylib`Curl_multi_closed + 122
    frame #2: 0x000000010aedd252 libcares.2.dylib`ares__close_sockets + 222
    frame #3: 0x000000010aee59fd libcares.2.dylib`end_query + 307
    frame #4: 0x000000010aee631c libcares.2.dylib`process_answer + 1374
    frame #5: 0x000000010aee4ef3 libcares.2.dylib`processfds + 1428
    frame #6: 0x000000010a997963 libcurl.4.dylib`waitperform + 244
    frame #7: 0x000000010a99777c libcurl.4.dylib`Curl_resolver_is_resolved + 55
    frame #8: 0x000000010a9824e5 libcurl.4.dylib`multi_runsingle + 2645
    frame #9: 0x000000010a981995 libcurl.4.dylib`curl_multi_perform + 133
    frame #10: 0x000000010a97b49e libcurl.4.dylib`curl_easy_perform + 369
    frame #11: 0x00000001095461cc php`zif_curl_exec + 100
    frame #12: 0x0000000109897e26 php`ZEND_DO_FCALL_BY_NAME_SPEC_RETVAL_USED_HANDLER + 266
    frame #13: 0x000000010984fc3c php`execute_ex + 98
    frame #14: 0x000000010984fdb8 php`zend_execute + 318
    frame #15: 0x0000000109814932 php`zend_execute_scripts + 277
    frame #16: 0x00000001097c06e9 php`php_execute_script + 637
    frame #17: 0x00000001098bfaa1 php`do_cli + 3855
    frame #18: 0x00000001098bea28 php`main + 1229
    frame #19: 0x00007fff5a6393d5 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There's currently an issue with curl-openssl on mac that affects some people. I have it on one machine but not on another. The curl issue is here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/40812

I've previously tried downgrading curl, re-installing from source etc (this was better but still has some issues)

A curl release should be due today (17th July 2019) to fix the issue